# How to download data using script?

Tags: shell, download

I want to download bulk number of data from ZINC database. The ZINC identifiers are like this; 
ZINC18923487, ZINC45780921, ZINC45670936 etc. I aim  to download almost 10,000 identifiers. Can some guide me, how to write a script, or use an already developed script to download my data.
ZINC database is an online free database, http://zinc.docking.org.
I am sorry, if my question is too general, or inappropriate.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What OS are you on? What tools you have expertise in (so that we can better direct you using that tool)?

Answer (score 0):

That website provides a huge repository of information in variety of formats.

1. There are some .xls (MS Excel) files, that you can click and view in any excel viewer (like MS Excel or open source alternatives).
2. There are lot of databases in gzip format (.gz files). In order to download these, you need a unix/like like operating (or Cygwin or MinGW or some such alternative). That environment specifically needs csh

   - csh (C-Shell) to run their scripts
   - Wget in order to fetch parse the links on their site
   - Curl in order to fetch the database files
   - gzip in order to uncompress the zipped files

If you are a programmer with shell scripting skills, you can mash your way into the databases in many different ways, using alternative tools.